# Is there another way to remove an element from an array without a for loop?

Tags: javascript

I am using this code:

```
self.contents.forEach(function (elem, index) {
    if (elem['contentId'] === self.content.contentId)
        self.contents.splice(index, 1);
})
```

With new browser capabilities, is there an easier way to remove the object from `self.contents` that has a `contentId` matching `self.content.contentId`.

Note that there is only ever one object in the contents array that has that Id

Comment: I don't think there is another way than using a loop, but if there will be only 1 match during an iteration.. then you can use .some() instead of .forEach() so that we will not have to iterate over all the elements

Comment: Might not be applicable here, but in situations where I need to be able to address a piece of data by id/number/string, I usually use an object instead of an array to store the data.

Comment: Use `.filter()` to create another array without the given one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store your elements to an object with keys as their ID, then retrieve them by indexing on that:

```
//Procedure to add in the object, modify to meet your needs.
var storeObject = {};
storeObject[1] = elemWithID1;
storeObject[5] = elemWithID5;
```

Then, you can do:

```
elem = storeObject[self.content.contentId];
```

Considering that you practically use hash tables in that case, this mapping will have a probably average `O(1)` complexity than just by iteration search which will have `O(n)`, which is better (consider it faster).

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
var array = [2, 5, 9];
array.indexOf(2);
```

this returns index of element after that use [**INDEX OF**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```
array.splice(index, 1);
```

there is another method but it is Jquery based... [**JQUERY $.inArray**](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

```
$.inArray( ele, array );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function.

```
var pos = self.contents.map(function (e){
    return e.contentId;
}).indexOf(self.content.contentId);
self.contents.splice(pos, 1);
```